# Ubuntu 20 clean installation failed to install Nvidia drivers

Tags: drivers, cuda

My computer is Dell XPS-15.

After clean installation, when trying to install Nvidia drivers, using Software Updater, or by installing packages from Nvidia site, with CUDA or without it,  I am getting failures.

My computer is Dual boot ( with Windows 10, where GPU works ok ).
Last time I installed Ubuntu 20 on same computer, it worked smoothly.  Hence it seems something got broken in the installation script.

The failures I got looks like this one:

```
 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main i386 libpciaccess0 i386 0.16-0ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.115.211.70 80]
```

Hence, it seems maybe the Local Server is messed up.

Any good advice ?

Thanks
Shmuel Hass

Comment: Did you try to install the 32 bit or BIOS version? It should be the 64 bit and booted in UEFI mode. You then use Safe mode and install optional restricted extras to get nVidia driver. Driver is not in Software but in Drivers and should only be installed from Ubuntu repository, not from nVidia. If you have working system totally unstall/purge nVidia & install from repository. nVidia install, purge if needed.
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2383560&p=13735336#post13735336

Comment: @oldfred - why loading drivers from Nvidia site is not recommended ?

Comment: Better to install nVidia drivers from Ubuntu repository. They are current and updated to work with Ubuntu. With the nVidia drivers they are not reinstalled when a new kernel is downloaded. So you have to reinstall with every kernel update. The Ubuntu version of the nVidia driver is automatically updated, so you do not normally have to do anything extra.  Also installing a new driver, does not correctly replace an older driver. You mus totally purge any & all old drivers before installing a new one to avoid conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

Hit Win-key and type `additional`, click `Additional Drivers` - in there you should have Nvidia drivers (several versions) listed, pick one, try to get it running; it might be that the very latest one doesn't run though.

If not present in the list, check that the first tab (left of Additional Drivers) has a tick SET for `Software restricted by copyright ...` and check again.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by changing the server of Ubuntu updates to MAIN instead of LOCAL. Now CUDA and NVIDIA drivers are installed correctly and run perfectly.

How come the local server in Israel is messed up and how come I'm the only one that is affected ? I wasted several days on this .....

@Hannu - I tried what you suggested and also other methods, all failed

Comment: If there is an issue with the servers in Israel, you need to report that to ubuntu-mirrors@lists.ubuntu.com - that's not something Ask Ubuntu has insight into.